# Is there anything I can do to force an element onto the second column?

Tags: html, css

[image]

As seen in the picture above, I have a textarea, some notes, and a preview of my current note. What I want to do, is *force* the preview note onto the second column, where the placeholder note is currently located. I cannot think of any way to do this with my current implementation, using css columns.

```
.notes {
    // .notes is the container for all notes
    column-gap: 12px;
    column-fill: balance;
    column-count: 5;
}
```

My html looks somewhat like the following

```
<div class="notes">
    <div class="editor">...</div>
    <div class="previewNote">...</div>

    <div class="note">...</div>
    <div class="note">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

*I intentionally left out unrelated parts of the css and html*

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would just use normal css and float the elements.

```
div.notes div {
width:50%;
padding:0;
margin:0;
float:left;
}
```

And then manually set which ones you want to be on the right using `float:right;`

```
div.notes .previewNote {
float:right;
}
```

Sections will display based first on whether they are floated right or left, and then based on which is in the HTML first. As long as the div of class previewNote is the first div floated right in the HTML, it will be the first one on the right to display.